# How to remove Azure On-Premises Data Gateway connection gateway installations?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-logic-apps

the [Azure On-Premises Data Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install) got installed with the wrong Azure region settings on a Virtual Machine in Azure. After uninstalling the on-premises Data Gateway, the original connection gateway installation is not removed and a new one with the same name cannot be created anymore. I even tried deleting the Virtual Machine to see if they would disappear. This had no impact.

When creating the on-premises data gateway in the Azure Portal I can still select the old installation names.

Also the following request returns those installations:

`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/Microsoft.Web/locations/northeurope/connectionGatewayInstallations?api-version=2015-08-01-preview`

[image: Connection Gateway Installations]

I tried removing them with a `DELETE` http request to the connectionGatewayInstallations endpoint, but that returned a 400 Bad Request:

`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/northeurope/connectionGatewayInstallations/{connectionGatewayInstallationId}?api-version=2015-08-01-preview`

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "DisallowedResourceOperation",
        "message": "The operation 'delete' on resource type 'locations/connectionGatewayInstallations' is disallowed."
    }
}
```

Anyone having any ideas on how to delete those connectionGatewayInstallations?

Comment: Once the on-premise data gateway is uninstalled, you should no longer see it listed under connection gateway installations. Do you still see your gateway in the PowerBI portal? (under settings -> manage gateways)

Comment: We're not using PowerBI at the moment.

Looking at some blog post from May, functionality to delete installations will be added soon: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/on-premises-data-gateway-functionality-goes-ga-in-azure/

"**Delete gateway resource in Azure**
You can now delete your gateway connection resource in Azure and associate your gateway to a different Azure resource. The ability to delete the gateway installation is coming soon."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this issue resolved itself. The endpoint uri for the connection gateway installation has changed in the api and the old connections are gone now.